# Sort comments by id and related answers in PHP-MySql

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I have a MySql comments table. Some comments in this table are *"simple"* comments, some other are *"replies"* to comments. This table contains a *"id"* field and a *"reply"* field, to indicate which comment the reply refers to. In the following example, I have simple comments 1,4,7; comments 2,3,6 are replies to 1; comment 5 is a reply to 4.

[image: unordered comments]

My goal is to retrieve and display comments in PHP, ordered first by comment id and then by its replies. This way:

[image: ordered by id and replies]

I've thought to create a MySql query for each comment, to retrieve its replies; but I think it's not efficient because in this case I must query the DB many times (most of them without results, if comment doesn't have replies). Is there an *efficient* way to perform this goal? Maybe create a unique MySql query and then elaborate results in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the comments linked to an article by its `id` ?

Comment: Actually, comments can also be not related to a specific article. They can be left from users a the received service (i.e. after a stay in an hotel). Is it important? I thought my problem was related to comments table and not if comments refer to an article.

Comment: You can also think simple comments to have "0" on "reply" field, if can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be able to order this in SQL like this (I am assuming the blank values of reply are nulls)

```
SELECT id, comment, reply
FROM comments_table
ORDER BY IF(reply IS NOT NULL, reply, id), id
```

Tested on sqlfiddle:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf75b/1

Comment: This is simply great @Kickstart! Neat and effective. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysqli_result::fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to get result to array.
Then create an array of comments
like:

```
//assuming $result has array of all comments sorted in assending order of number of comments.
//array(0=>array('id'=>1,'comment'=>'Nice article','reply'=>''), 1=>....
$comments=array();
foreach($result as $value){
if($value['reply']!='')
 $comments[$value['id']]=array('comment'=>$value['comment'],'reply' => array());
else
 $comments[$value['reply']]['reply'][$value['id']]=$value['comment']
}
```

This will created a array of comments containing an array of replies.